# Can't make split() function to do what I want

Tags: java, split, token

i have a problem with `split()`. When entering a text like "This is a text" it only prints "This".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Enter bta3 ");
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String toParse = s1.next();
        String delims = "[ ]+";
        String[] tokens = toParse.split(delims);
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            {
                System.out.println(tokens[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want it to print?

Comment: [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a _regex_ as the parameter

Comment: Note: you have an unnecessary set of braces. You have `for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) { { System.out.println(tokens[i]); } }` but it should be `for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) { System.out.println(tokens[i]); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not with `split` but with `Scanner`, which by default uses one or more continues whitespaces as delimiter, so `s1.next()` will return only one word from user input (with no whitespaces) which means

```
String toParse = s1.next();
```

for input like `This is a text` will become `This` (so there are no whitespaces to split on)

If you want to read entire data from user input use `s1.nextLine()`.